# External HDD being detected on Smart TV but not on PC

Tags: external-hard-drive, smart-tv

I've 1TB external HDD. When i connect it to my smart TV it gets connected normally. I can view movie songs etc but at the same time when i connect it to my pc it does not. It is not being detected on PC. Tried changing OS. Doesn't help at all. Any solution?

Comment: What is the HDD model and what OS are you using ? Are the USB ports correctly enabled ?

Comment: Does it "see" the device but not see any partitions? It cos be using a file system that isn't recognised - many DVR systems do this.

Comment: Very often SMART TVs will reformat external drives once they are connected to them. Please specify the model of the TV or check with the manufacturer. Also make sure that you are connecting the HDD directly to the USB port on the computer and not through a USB hub.

Comment: I think we are missing some information that could help.  Similar to what Overmind was thinking, if it's the USB port, other than it not being enabled or connected, it's possible the USB driver could be bad and needs reinstalled.  What i would suggest checking first is disk manager.  Connect the HDD, open disk manager (use the search bar in the start menu), and see if it shows up there.  You can unplug and replug it in to see if one of the drives disappears.  It may need to be assigned a drive letter or reformatted to work with the computer.